# ActivityIndicator in xamarin forms not working

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin form. I have xaml page where I want to display `ActivityIndicator` when button is clicked.

It is working when I set its property `IsRunning = True` in `xaml` but not working when i set this property from code.

Here is `xaml`

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <StackLayout>
                <Image Source="imgmain.png" Aspect="AspectFit"></Image>
                <Image Source="Companylogo.png" Aspect="AspectFit"></Image>
            </StackLayout>
            <!--<BoxView WidthRequest="1"></BoxView>-->
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="10">
                <Grid Column="2" Row="4">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition  Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition  Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition  Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label  Text="Username :" FontSize="20"  TextColor="DarkBlue"></Label>
                    <Entry Placeholder="Username" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="EntryUsername"></Entry>
                    <Label Text="Password :" FontSize="20" TextColor="DarkBlue"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
                    <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  x:Name="EntryPassword"></Entry>
                    <Button Text="Login"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"></Button>
                    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ActivityIndicatorLoading" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}"  IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}" Color="DarkBlue"></ActivityIndicator>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
```

code is as below

```
public partial class Login : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        set
        {
            if (isLoading != value)
            {
                isLoading = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsLoading"));
                }
            }
        }
        get { return isLoading; }
    }
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsLoading = false;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

        public void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetLoader(true);
            IsLoading = true;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EntryUsername.Text))
            {
                DisplayAlert("Alert", "Please enter username", "Ok");
                IsLoading = false;
                SetLoader(false);
                return;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EntryPassword.Text))
            {
                DisplayAlert("Alert", "Please enter password", "Ok");
                IsLoading = false;
                SetLoader(false);
                return;
            }

            LoginManager loginManager=new LoginManager();
            User obj = loginManager.ValidateUser(EntryUsername.Text.Trim(), EntryPassword.Text.Trim());
            if (obj == null)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error", "username/password is incorrect", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Current.Properties["FullName"] = obj.FirstName + " " + obj.LastName;
                Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
            }

            SetLoader(false);
            IsLoading = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no ' PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsLoading")); ' in getter of IsLoading property.

Then, there is no way to know its value's changed.

Please look here.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/

Edit : Sorry for my first answer.

You need to create a ViewModel class which has a 'IsLoading' property. And assign it to BindingContext property on the ContentPage. And set the PropertyChanged event on the IsLoading property at your ViewModel class. Finally, put boolean value on it, it would work. That's MvvM.

Comment: I have modified my code to add PropertyChanged but still not working. Could you please check

Comment: Opps, sorry, ContentPage has 'OnPropertyChanged' method already, so you could use it without declaring the new one?

Comment: And you should use ViewModel to make that kind of thing work. You didn't assign anything to BindingContext of ContentPage. Then, "{Binding IsLoading}" does not work.

Comment: I'm sorry about my first answer.

Comment: You need to create a ViewModel class which has IsLoading property. And assign it to BindingContext property on the ContentPage. And set the PropertyChanged event on the IsLoading property at your ViewModel class.  Finally, put boolean value on it, it would work. That's MvvM.

Comment: If you don't like this, just use 'ActivityIndicatorLoading.IsLoading = true'.